# Reindex equivalent of pandas columns headers

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
    A   C   D
0   3   4   6
1   5   4   8
2   7   4   6
```

and a list

```
l=['A','B','C','D']
```

How do I reindex the column headers with the list?

So the output is

```
   A   B   C  D
0  3      4   6
1  5      4   8
2  7      4   6
```

Comment: That's literally the `reindex` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `axis=1` parameter in the `reindex` method:

```
df.reindex(l, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   A   B  C  D
0  3 NaN  4  6
1  5 NaN  4  8
2  7 NaN  4  6
```

And, you can fillna with '', if you would like.

```
df.reindex(l, axis=1).fillna('')
```

Output:

```
   A B  C  D
0  3    4  6
1  5    4  8
2  7    4  6
```

Comment: @fred.schwartz would you mind accepting this solution?